# Druid SQL group by date

Tags: sql, druid

I'm writing an SQL query for Apache Druid and I would like to group results by date. I'm used to DB2 and I would typically do something like:

`SELECT DATE(TIMESTAMP), COUNT(*) FROM my_table GROUP BY (DATE(TIMESTAMP))`

I'm using the `/druid/v2/sql` API endpoint and passing in the query in a POST. I get an SQL parsing error when I try this. I know that I can group by day with something like

`SELECT EXTRACT(day FROM timestamp), COUNT(*) FROM my_table GROUP BY 1`

but I would like the full date if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('day', TIMESTAMP), COUNT(*)
FROM my_table
GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('day', TIMESTAMP);
```

Answer (score 0):

Druid houses timeseries data having `__time` as PK.
Following SQL script in Druid might work grouping data Year, Month, Day wise.

```
SELECT TIME_EXTRACT(__time, 'DAY') AS dt, TIME_EXTRACT(__time, 'MONTH') AS mn, TIME_EXTRACT(__time, 'YEAR') AS yr, COUNT(1) AS cnt
FROM <datasource_name/table_name>
WHERE __time BETWEEN '<start_datetime>' and '<end_datetime>'
GROUP BY TIME_EXTRACT(__time, 'DAY'), TIME_EXTRACT(__time, 'MONTH'), TIME_EXTRACT(__time, 'YEAR')
HAVING cnt >= <Threshold_Value>
ORDER BY yr, mn, dt, cnt DESC
```